# How to make parent useEffect hook execute before child useEffect

Tags: reactjs

In React, if a child component and a parent component both have useEffect hooks, why does the child component's useEffect hook execute before the parent's?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Parent() {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Parent useEffect");
    // Perform some side effect logic
  }, []);



  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Parent Component</h1>
      <Child/>
    </div>
  );
}

function Child() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Child useEffect");
    // Perform some side effect logic
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Child Component</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In React, if a child component and a parent component both have useEffect hooks, I expect it is possible to make the parent component's useEffect hook execute before the child's.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could do something like the following:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function Parent() {
  const [parent_useEffect_done, set_parent_useEffect_done] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Parent useEffect");
    // Perform some side effect logic
    set_parent_useEffect_done(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Parent Component</h1>
      <Child parent_useEffect_done={parent_useEffect_done} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Child({ parent_useEffect_done }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if(parent_useEffect_done) {
      console.log("Child useEffect");
    }
    
    // Perform some side effect logic
  }, [parent_useEffect_done]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Child Component</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent />
    </div>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app'));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

This records whether the parent has completed its useEffect in state, passes that down to the child, uses the child's useEffect dependency array to decide whether to run or not.

For your original example I think we can check that it is running the child useEffect first:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

let effect_count = 0;

function Parent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Parent useEffect " + ++effect_count);
    // Perform some side effect logic
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Parent Component</h1>
      <Child />
    </div>
  );
}

function Child() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Child useEffect " + ++effect_count);
    
    // Perform some side effect logic
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Child Component</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent />
    </div>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app'));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: According to the chatgpt or some articles that i have checked parent execute first then child executes.

Comment: If we have nested hierarchy of components then it is difficult to manage your logic.

Comment: @RavinderSingh I'm not sure I have a good sense of what the actual problem you're trying to solve is, but have you considered doing the work in the parent component and then just passing down the data to the children?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

According to the React documentation, the `useEffect` is called during the mount: https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect. The parent useEffect should be called before the child one. The reason you see the console of child one is probably because of the console.log which is an async function: https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html#printing-in-asynchook-callbacks

Not sure it exists a real "clean" solution for that. What would be your use case?

A workaround would be to render conditionally the child so the condition is the execution of the parent `useEffect`

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Parent() {
  const [triggered, setTriggered] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Parent useEffect");
    // Perform some side effect logic

   setTriggered(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Parent Component</h1>
      {triggered && (
        <Child/>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function Child() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Child useEffect");
    // Perform some side effect logic
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Child Component</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: According to the chatgpt or some articles that i have checked parent execute first then child executes.If we have nested hierarchy of components then it is difficult to manage your logic.

Comment: You are right, the useEffect is triggered during the component mount so the parent should be called before the child one.

Comment: The functions are maybe called in the right order but since the console log is an async function you see the log in the wrong order. Have you tried to use the debugger with a breakpoint to test?

Comment: I have checked with debugger break point it execute the child use Effect first.

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to swap the parent's `useEffect` with a `useLayoutEffect`.

**Example:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect } from "react";

function Parent() {
  ...

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log("Parent useEffect");
    // Perform some side effect logic
  }, []);

  ...
}

function Child() {
  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Child useEffect");
    // Perform some side effect logic
  }, []);

  ...
}
```

The reason this works is because, as mentioned in the [`documentation`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useLayoutEffect):

> useLayoutEffect is a version of useEffect that fires before the browser repaints the screen.

This would do the trick, but usually this type of situation points to some antipattern.
And either way you are creating an implicit dependency here, which is not really advised.
So I suggest to first re-think this and try to figure out if there is a more straightforward way to achieve whatever it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Also doesn't works with useLayoutEffect

Comment: Yes it does. Here's an example https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-leaf-275ucs?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yeah works as expected. But if have another child element like child2. Then the output is printed on screen Parnet Child2 Child1. That was same issue. If we have single parent child component then it is right way for deep level not works.

Comment: As mentioned before, you are not supposed to have an implicit deep level dependency between `useEffect` hooks in such a way. This structure is very brittle and probably points to a less than ideal code architecture. So I suggest taking a step back and re-assessing whatever it is you're trying to build in-order to find a better pattern for it.